# Angular + Ui-router: $stateParams is empty inside Interceptor when using resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, interceptor

### What I want to achieve:

Send a token that I get from the url stateParams with every request. For this i'm using an http Interceptor.

The interceptor looks like this:

```
.factory('myInterceptor', function($stateParams){
    return {
        request: function(config){
            config.url = config.url + '?text=' + $stateParams.token;
            return config;
        }
    }
})
```

### My problem

Inside the interceptor, the $stateParams is empty when $http is called inside the resolve. However when I call it from inside the controller, it works fine.

**Working example**:

> Using $http inside the controller: http://jsfiddle.net/sikko/drLg06w8/8/

```
controller: function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.post('/echo/jsonp').success(function(response){
    $scope.text = response.text;
  });
}
```

**Non Working example**:

> Using $http inside the resolve: http://jsfiddle.net/sikko/drLg06w8/7/

```
resolve: {
  resolveVar: function($http){
    return $http.post('/echo/jsonp').success(function(response){
      return response.text;
    });
  }
},
controller: function ($scope, resolveVar) {
  $scope.text = resolveVar.data.text;
}
```

I did console.log in both examples so you can see that $stateParams is empty when using resolve.

My Guess is that the resolve cycle is called before that $stateParams is made available by angular or something like that... But I have no clue how to fix it... Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you actually reading `$stateParams`?

Comment: The full code is on the jsFiddle link for both working and non working examples. I'll update the question to clarify.